# Why can I connect to sql server 2008 via odbc but not through vb.net code?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, odbc, sqlclient

I'm supporting an old vb.net program whose database it connected to was moved from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008.  Is there a setting on SQL Server 2008 which will allow ODBC connections to access the database but not allow VB.NET to connect to it programmatically?

the error i keep receiving in the app is:

> An error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to the
>   server.  When connecting to SQL Server
>   2005, this failure may be caused by
>   the fact that under the default
>   settings SQL Server does not allow
>   remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)

however I can connect to it when I create a system dsn to the sql server instance and through VS2005's Tools >> Connect to Database.

Here is the code I'm using to connect:

```
dim strC as string 
strC = "data source=bob; database=subscribers; user id=bobuser; password=passme" 
dim connection as New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strC)  
try     
   connection.open() 
catch ex as Exception     
   msgbox(ex.message) 
end try  
connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such setting but it is possible because: You are able to access your sever via ODBC because using an ODBC DSN creates a sort of local bridge to the server. Trying to connect to the server from VB.NET code with the SqlClient library from a client machine requires your Sql Server to accept remote connections...

Check this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd857537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for help.

In brief:

- You need to set Sql Server to allow remote connections
- You need to make sure your firewall isn't blocking Sql Server's port(s)
- Make sure TCP/IP is enabled as a comm. mechanism for Sql Server

Comment: would developing a windows application in VS2005 make a difference to connect to a sql server 2008 database versus using VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

Start > Run > "CLICONFG" (No quotes)

In the SQL Server Client Network Utility, enable Named Pipes over TCP/IP